# Parse JSON into U-SQL then convert to csv

Tags: json, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to convert some telemetry data that is in JSON format into CSV format, then write it out to a file, using U-SQL.

The problem is that some of the JSON key values have periods in them, and so when I'm doing the SELECT operation, U-SQL is not recognizing them. When I check the output file, all that I am seeing is the values for "p1". How can I represent the names of the JSON key names in the script so that they are recognized. Thanks in advance for any help!

Code:

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY MATSDevDB.[Newtonsoft.Json];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY MATSDevDB.[Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats]; 

USING Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json;


@jsonDocuments = 
    EXTRACT jsonString string 
    FROM @"adl://xxxx.azuredatalakestore.net/xxxx/{*}/{*}/{*}/telemetry_{*}.json" 
    USING Extractors.Tsv(quoting:false);

@jsonify = 
    SELECT Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(jsonString) AS json 
    FROM @jsonDocuments;

@columnized = SELECT 
            json["EventInfo.Source"] AS EventInfoSource,
            json["EventInfo.InitId"] AS EventInfoInitId,
            json["EventInfo.Sequence"] AS EventInfoSequence,
            json["EventInfo.Name"] AS EventInfoName,
            json["EventInfo.Time"] AS EventInfoTime,
            json["EventInfo.SdkVersion"] AS EventInfoSdkVersion,
            json["AppInfo.Language"] AS AppInfoLanguage,
            json["UserInfo.Language"] AS UserInfoLanguage,
            json["DeviceInfo.BrowserName"] AS DeviceInfoBrowswerName,
            json["DeviceInfo.BrowserVersion"] AS BrowswerVersion,
            json["DeviceInfo.OsName"] AS DeviceInfoOsName,
            json["DeviceInfo.OsVersion"] AS DeviceInfoOsVersion,
            json["DeviceInfo.Id"] AS DeviceInfoId,
            json["p1"] AS p1,
            json["PipelineInfo.AccountId"] AS PipelineInfoAccountId, 
            json["PipelineInfo.IngestionTime"] AS PipelineInfoIngestionTime, 
            json["PipelineInfo.ClientIp"] AS PipelineInfoClientIp,
            json["PipelineInfo.ClientCountry"] AS PipelineInfoClientCountry,
            json["PipelineInfo.IngestionPath"] AS PipelineInfoIngestionPath,
            json["AppInfo.Id"] AS AppInfoId,
            json["EventInfo.Id"] AS EventInfoId,
            json["EventInfo.BaseType"] AS EventInfoBaseType,
            json["EventINfo.IngestionTime"] AS EventINfoIngestionTime
    FROM @jsonify;

OUTPUT @columnized
TO "adl://xxxx.azuredatalakestore.net/poc/TestResult.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv(quoting : false);
```

JSON:

{"EventInfo.Source":"JS_default_source","EventInfo.Sequence":"1","EventInfo.Name":"daysofweek","EventInfo.Time":"2018-01-25T21:09:36.779Z","EventInfo.SdkVersion":"ACT-Web-JS-2.6.0","AppInfo.Language":"en","UserInfo.Language":"en-US","UserInfo.TimeZone":"-08:00","DeviceInfo.BrowserName":"Chrome","DeviceInfo.BrowserVersion":"63.0.3239.132","DeviceInfo.OsName":"Mac OS X","DeviceInfo.OsVersion":"10","p1":"V1","PipelineInfo.IngestionTime":"2018-01-25T21:09:33.9930000Z","PipelineInfo.ClientCountry":"CA","PipelineInfo.IngestionPath":"FastPath","EventInfo.BaseType":"custom","EventInfo.IngestionTime":"2018-01-25T21:09:33.9930000Z"}

Comment: Do you have an example of the JSON file? The code alone does not help.

Comment: @MichaelRys Thanks for commenting. I've added parts of the original JSON file. Can't post the whole thing due to data confidentiality. My questions is: Do I need special syntax to escape the period in the JSON key values? The reason I ask is because the output file only has values for "p1", which is the only key that does not have any periods, so I am guessing that is the problem.

Comment: You have to quote the names that contain spaces, like wBob shows.

Comment: I know your issue is resolved. But can you share real time requirement around this issue. It helps me to understand the real usage of U-SQL. I am also having telemetry data in JSON format. before sending it to azure data lake do I have to convert it in to files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this to work with single quotes and single square brackets, eg

```
@columnized = SELECT 
            json["['EventInfo.Source']"] AS EventInfoSource,
...
```

Full code:

```
@columnized = SELECT 
            json["['EventInfo.Source']"] AS EventInfoSource,
            json["['EventInfo.InitId']"] AS EventInfoInitId,
            json["['EventInfo.Sequence']"] AS EventInfoSequence,
            json["['EventInfo.Name']"] AS EventInfoName,
            json["['EventInfo.Time']"] AS EventInfoTime,
            json["['EventInfo.SdkVersion']"] AS EventInfoSdkVersion,
            json["['AppInfo.Language']"] AS AppInfoLanguage,
            json["['UserInfo.Language']"] AS UserInfoLanguage,
            json["['DeviceInfo.BrowserName']"] AS DeviceInfoBrowswerName,
            json["['DeviceInfo.BrowserVersion']"] AS BrowswerVersion,
            json["['DeviceInfo.OsName']"] AS DeviceInfoOsName,
            json["['DeviceInfo.OsVersion']"] AS DeviceInfoOsVersion,
            json["['DeviceInfo.Id']"] AS DeviceInfoId,
            json["p1"] AS p1,
            json["['PipelineInfo.AccountId']"] AS PipelineInfoAccountId, 
            json["['PipelineInfo.IngestionTime']"] AS PipelineInfoIngestionTime, 
            json["['PipelineInfo.ClientIp']"] AS PipelineInfoClientIp,
            json["['PipelineInfo.ClientCountry']"] AS PipelineInfoClientCountry,
            json["['PipelineInfo.IngestionPath']"] AS PipelineInfoIngestionPath,
            json["['AppInfo.Id']"] AS AppInfoId,
            json["['EventInfo.Id']"] AS EventInfoId,
            json["['EventInfo.BaseType']"] AS EventInfoBaseType,
            json["['EventINfo.IngestionTime']"] AS EventINfoIngestionTime
    FROM @jsonify;
```

My results:

[image: Results]

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Had another question: I'm trying to keep my output files in the same structure as my input files. Do you know how to state the output file string so that it matches the input file string, when the input file string is dynamic (As written in the original question)? Thanks for all of the help

Comment: This is an oft-requested feature and is on the feedback list here which also shows a workaround with Powershell in the meantime:  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/10550388-support-dynamic-output-file-names-in-adla

Comment: Is converting to CSV is must before getting them processed by data lake engine? can't I process all the incoming json telemetry directly in azure data lake?